# IBM Cloud Private - Deploy Node Js application

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private

We have configured IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0.3 
We have sample node application. We need to deploy the same in ICP console.
We have followed the procedures listed in the below link.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/app_center/create_helm_cli.html

Please suggest suitable methods.

Answer (score 0):

to deploy an application, you can deploy using

1. cli
2. ICP UI

### CLI

1. using helm chart you created

   - i have a sample project where I shows a java app how it is package and deploy, hopes it helps
     https://github.com/ibmcloudprivate2/wildfly
2. using deployment file

## UI

1. using helm chart you created and added into the UI catalog and deploy using it

   - see above .
2. using deployment and service

   - the following project, i have package a ng sample and shows how to deploy using the UI Workloads/Deployment/Create Deployment and Network Access/Services/Create Service
     https://github.com/ibmcloudprivate2/ng4-admin

hopes it helps.